# stackoverflow tag?

Tags: feature-request

A new question was just asked which is tagged with the tag [`stackoverflow`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) so I visited the tag page, which has 12 questions.

My question is, why do we have this tag. I don't see any relevance or need for a tag called `stackoverflow`. Can we remove the tag from the 12 questions and then ban the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these questions, except the last one which I closed just now, are somehow related to the Stack Exchange network. So the tag isn't completely useless, it should probably just renamed to `stackexchange`. And it needs a wiki.

Comment: How do we rename the tag? Agree that the name `stackexchange` is better suited

Comment: @PieterGoosen A moderator can do that.

Comment: OK, thanks for your input. Appreciated